# Angular Material tree how to insert an img/file

Tags: angular, image, tree

I just start with Angular and I can't find the solution anywhere. I searched for few days, but nothing.

I would like to:

1. insert a picture (no icon) in a material tree, how to do that? (cf comment in code)

**example:**
Here the is a dynamic tree, I would like sometimes insert picture added to the text, to illustrate:
[image: example]

*I found how to add an icon before each entry but it's not that I am looking for...
my idea: I try to add a new variable in the array (named "file", like "name"), which the content was the path of the image or null, but it doesn't work?

2. I would like linkify some entries (cf comment in code), some text have to be a link

Please somebody could assist me ?

Here under the code:

documentation.component.ts:

```js
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource } from '@angular/material/tree';
// import { UserInformation } from 'src/app/interfaces/user-information/user-information';

interface DocNode {
  name: string;
  // file: string | null;
  children?: DocNode[];
}

const TREE_DATA: DocNode[] = [
{
    name: 'Parent title',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Child Title ',
        children: [
          { name: 'To complete', // file : null },
          { name: 'To complete', // file: './assets/img.png'},
          { name: 'To complete', // file : null }, 
          { name: 'https://monsite.net/home.html', // file : null }, // *****linkify this one*****
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'To complete',
        children: [
          { name: '1. To complete',// file : null },
          { name: '2. To complete', // file: './assets/otherImg.png' },
          { name: '3. To complete',// file : null},
          { name: '4. To complete',// file : null },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documentation',
  templateUrl: './documentation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documentation.component.scss'],
})
export class DocumentationComponent {
  title = 'Documentation Z2C';
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<DocNode>((node) => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<DocNode>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: DocNode) =>
    !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

documentation.component.html:

```html
//to insert somewhere :  <img src='{{ node.file }}'alt='screenshot'>

<div class="documentation">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  <mat-tree
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    [treeControl]="treeControl"
    class="documentation-tree"
  >
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
      <li class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
        {{ node.name }}
      </li>
    </mat-tree-node>

    <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
      <li>
        <div class="mat-tree-node">
          <button
            mat-icon-button
            matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name"
          >
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{
                treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'
              }}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          {{ node.name }}
        </div>
        <ul
          [class.documentation-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)"
        >
          <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </mat-nested-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want image icon ?
I couldn't understand you question

Comment: No icon, I would like insert a picture to illustrate the text

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that it is not possible or pretty difficult...
So I used https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview
Now it's ok